# Is it possible to Shut down a local pc with group policies programatically through .net application?

Tags: .net, wmi, group-policy

I have a local application running with an user than have a group policy indicating this user can’t shutdown the pc.

And then I use your code, but when I ask by user and password to impersonate my app. I received the next error

System.Management.ManagementException: it’s not possible to use the user’s credentials for the local connections

Regards

Comment: So you're trying to get around the group policy by writing an application that allows the user to shut down the PC?

Comment: Yes, basically I have and application in a public computer with hardening, so the user can only run my app and anything else (not shutdown inclusive).
And then I have a key combination on my app to shut down the computer previous identification (username and password) and I expect my code to get connect locally with other credentials and shutdown the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using the [`Process.Start()` overload that allows one to supply a username and password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed04yy3t.aspx).  I would execute `shutdown.exe` on that new process.

Of course, storing the username and password is not terribly secure and could probably be hacked by anyone that wanted to spend enough time with it.